# Detail Explanation of LaunchMode in Android

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, launchmode

I want to learn `the concept and idea for using launchMode` in Android. When to use which mode and a little detail about each of them.

Because I am facing an issue in Animation Transition between Activity. As i go from Activity A to B. Amimation shows smoothly but when i go back to Activity A by calling finish() Animation doesn't look as it goes from B to A. I googled it and some answer says to add `singleInstance or singleTask to Activity in manifest`. And some say to add flag Activity_reorder_to_front and so many other answer. Now I don't want anyone to solve my issue. I just want to learn these concept to get my job done myself.

and also suggest me which one is preferable for my current situation. I must call finish and i don't want to create a new Instance of Activity A.

Comment: check this link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: Do not use these launch modes. They are only to be used in special circumstances (example: you are building a HOME screen replacement). You can do everything you need using `standard` or `singleTop` launch modes. Please post the code you are using to do your animation transitions.